# Windows forms Listbox won't show the right text for each item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I was actually done with the project. It was tested and worked perfectly and showed the right values.

Today it won't show the right text in the listbox.

Here is my code:

```
private void filmBtnLoadFilms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilmServiceClient filmClient = new FilmServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IFilmService");
    ShowServiceClient showClient = new ShowServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IShowService");

    FilmRecord[] list = null;
    try
    {
        //Retrieve all films
        if (list == null)
        {
            list = filmClient.RetrieveAllFilms();
        }
        if (filmList.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            filmList.Items.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var film in list)
        {
            filmList.Items.Add(film);
        }

        this.filmList.DataSource = list;
        this.filmList.DisplayMember = "Title";
        this.filmList.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
    catch
    {
        logLabel.Text = "Film kunne ikke indlæses";
    }
    showClient.Close();
    filmClient.Close();
}
```

Hope you can help with finding the answer. Upfront thanks.

New update.
If I move the calls come datasource, datamember and value member then filmList.ValueMember gives an argument exception that was unhandled.

Comment: What is it showing now then?

Comment: The path -> libraryname.wcfservicereference.record.object something like that

Comment: Since you bind list into filmList, clearing filmList and adding the content of list one by one isn't required. Anyway, since the app depend on (I presume) a web service, have you checked the response? Do you use some webscrapper? If so, the target format may changed which cause the wrong result.

Comment: I do get the right data in from my WCF. But it just won't set the right name for the object in the listbox.

Comment: Awesome `catch`. Seems you developed the most stable application ever.

Answer (score 0):

You adding items manually

```
foreach (var film in list)
{
    filmList.Items.Add(film);
}
```

Then you use `DataSource`.

```
this.filmList.DataSource = list;
```

This is two different methods for filling listbox with the items

By the way setting `DataSource` will remove existing items if they was added
On other hand adding items manually after `DataSource` was set will throw `System.ArgumentException`

For displayed text `ListBox` call property of item which name was given in the `DisplayMember`
If name is empty or property not accessible `ListBox` reset `DisplayMember = String.Empty` and `.ToString()` will be called.
This is a reason why you get name of the type in your list.

If you want using `DataSource` for filling listbox with items, then remove code block where items added manually, 
then clearing items(`filmList.Items.Clear();`) is unnecessary too

*Update after comment*
Make sure properties used for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are public

This is working code for me:

```
private void filmBtnLoadFilms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilmServiceClient filmClient = new FilmServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IFilmService");
    ShowServiceClient showClient = new ShowServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IShowService");

    try
    {
        this.filmList.DisplayMember = "Title";
        this.filmList.ValueMember = "Id";
        this.filmList.DataSource = filmClient.RetrieveAllFilms();
    }
    catch
    {
        logLabel.Text = "Film kunne ikke indlæses";
    }
    showClient.Close();
    filmClient.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have now changed the methods to use the datasource only. Still I get that path of my WCF record and not the title of the objects variable.

Comment: It optimized the code but the DisplayMember is not showing the title but rather "desktopclient.cinemaservicereference..." and so on.

Comment: @McBoman, please check that properties `Title` and `ID` of type `FilmRecord` have `public` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, do not fill the data both ways to your ListBox. You can either use `Items.Add` or the `DataSource`. Let's say, we use the latter. In this way you need not have to worry about `Items.Clear()` also. So, in order to display the title, you need to override the `ToString()` of your class, `FilmRecord`.

```
public override string ToString() { return this.Title; }
```

This is done because by default, your ListBox is also calling the `ToString` under the hood. Calling this method on a class object only reveals the name of the class and its namespace unless it is overridden to provide custom implementation.

Comment: For displayed text by default used `DisplayMember` property. Only if value is empty or accessing of that property fails `ToString()` will be called. In the OP's case your answer is workaround - not a solution

Comment: @Fabio you can't call it just a workaround to the problem. The question is to populate the ListBox to display the value instead of the type of the object. Now, this can be achieved in many ways. Two of which has already been tried in the OP. I just provided a working third option. There's no reason why it should be considered wrong or secondary to two mentioned above.

Comment: I agree - your solution work for display desired text. But based on the code `this.filmList.ValueMember = "Id";`, I think he want use `SelectedValue` property later. In your approach `SelectedValue` will be always null. That's why I comment your answer as workaround. And I think `ToString()` not good approach for displayed text, unless you type used only for displaying items in the List controls